# Different packages to reach out netbeans

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, netbeans, enterprise

How can I reach out sourcepackages/default packages/controlServlet. I want to use on

form action="**controlServlet**" method="POST"

but netBeans can't see controlServlet . How can I fix? I remember "*.././controlServlet*" something like that...

Answer (score 1):

You need to map the URL in the deployment descriptor `web.xml` under `WEB-INF`. The `<servlet-class>` should be fully qualified name of the class like : `package.classname`.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>controlServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ControlServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>controlServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/controlServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```